# Database indexable or serial overlapping possible?

Tags: database, postgresql

Im creating a database in postgresql where id of primary key is serial, and im doing the same within sql server, where id is identity(automatically adds an integer as id). My question is now, is it possible for the database to create two id's with the same value, if added exactly the same time? Or will the database sort that out and give them different id's anyways? I hope you guys understand what im trying to ask, any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible.

If it was possible the `serial` feature would be totally unusable.

Note, that values can be skipped or out of chronological (wall-clock) order.

Comment: It's called `serial` in Postgres, not `identity` but otherwise you are right

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, I thought he was going from Postgres to SQL Server. Then my answer is based on no knowledge at all but still correct :) Your retag was helpful.